# Speed Calculater

Tags: acceleration, speed, sensor

I want to make an android calculator which can calculate speed of a vehicle by using mobile sensors(accelerometer or GPS)
i am interested to calculate it by using accelerometer instead of GPS 
is it possible, if anyone have knowledge, guide me plz:

Comment: if the car always moved in a straight line it may be possible but the calculation would be thrown off as the car went around corners and up and down hills. The calculated speed would not be accurate.

Comment: How is this question related to accelerator physics?

Comment: Your phone's accelerometer is nowhere near accurate enough for long-term position calculations. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829097/android-accelerometer-accuracy-inertial-navigation).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot measure speed with an accelerometer, you can only measure acceleration.  What that means is, an accelerometer has not idea whether it is moving a 0 km/h or 100 km/h, it will only know if the speed it is at changes.

If you were to include in your calculator an option to define a "zero speed" (meaning, when the car is at rest you push a button to let the calculator know you are currently at 0 km/h) then the accelerometer could measure changes to that speed and *maybe* give you an accurate measurement of your current speed.  There is, however, at least one major problem with this:

**The accelerometer is unable to separate the acceleration of the car from the force/acceleration it feels because of gravity.** I think, due to this reason alone, building a calculator that measures the speed of a car using an accelerometer would likely be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: you could zero out gravity as a constant in the calculator.

Comment: @PeterR, that is true.  However, at that point the device would need to be held in the same exact position, otherwise any deviations from what it previously considered "level" would cause it to interpret an acceleration.

Comment: If a car goes over a speed breaker, it would read some acceleration.

Comment: @Quark, or even a hill

Comment: @Peter: It is theoretically not possible to separate gravity from acceleration, as Einstein's elevator Gedankenexperiment shows. Now, even for a scenario where we know that a strong constant acceleration term is overlaid by much weaker acceleration in mostly perpendicular direction the error calculus is extremely poor. Separating these components with a commercial accelerometer chip is not possible. One should point out that aerospace inertial navigation units place their accelerometers inside an extremely precise mechanical gyroscope, which removes the rotary degrees of freedom.

Comment: @CuriousOne It has nothing to do with Einstein or General Relativity. You can always deduct a constant for acceleration, The technology aspects are another issue.

Comment: @PeterR: The elevator experiment applies in Newtonian physics, as well. g is not a constant. It changes by about 0.5% between pole and equator and it changes by something like 0.3%, I believe with practically achievable elevation changes. These are non-trivial values. You would incur hundreds of km of elevation errors per hour if you only knew g up to these naturally occurring variations.

Comment: @PeterR I am not sure what you are saying. A car accelerates much more than those numbers. Physics deals with idealized sitautions and thought experiments based on principal. And in principal, you can eliminate a constant acceleration.